# Gibbs sampler for ARIMA AR(1) parameters: division by zero

Tags: bayesian, sampling, arima, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

Suppose the following AR(1) model:

$$ y_t = \mu + \phi (y_{t-1} - \mu) + \epsilon_t $$

with $\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Following issue arises when sampling from $P(\mu_i \;|\; \phi_{i-1}, \sigma^2_{i-1}, \bf{y})$ using a Gibbs procedure. Assuming uniform $\mu$-prior:

$$ \mu_i \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\frac{(1-\phi_{i-1})\Sigma_{t=2}^T (y_t - \phi_{i-1} y_{t-1})}{\Sigma_{t=2}^T (1-\phi_{i-1})}, \frac{\sigma^2_{i-1}}{\Sigma_{t=2}^T (1-\phi_{i-1})}\right)$$

The obvious problem is when $\phi_{i-1} = 1$. In such case $1-\phi_{i-1} = 0$ resulting in a division by zero.

Is my approach sane? I feel like I am missing something, since if it was, I should't be having this issue. Can someone elaborate?

Note: I am aware of non-stationary and the fact that I could centralize $\bf{y}$ to omit $\mu$. Still, that doesn't seem to me to explain the fundamental question above. I also went through some Bayesian econometrics literature, but have not found any mention of the above issue.

Comment: What's the prior on $\phi$? I am guessing what ever it is, it does not support $\phi = 1$, which means that unless you start from $\phi_1 = 1$, you will never run into the problem of $\phi_{i-1} = 1$.

Comment: @Greenparker, indeed, excluding $\phi = 1$ with the prior solves the issue indirectly, but still leaves room for odd cases very close to 1, which would skyrocket $\mu_i$. But you got a point.

Comment: And rightly so, because if $\phi$ is close to 1 for the model, then the true $\mu$ in the target will also be large.

Comment: You’d normally use a prior which is at least weakly informative for $\mu$. If you don’t have any prior information for it, it is typically a better idea to reformulate the model using an intercept instead of the unconditional mean.

Comment: @hejseb, You think that using a normal $\mu$-prior which is conjugate with the likelihood, would solve the the division by zero entirely? (On first look, I am not convinced, but by simplifying the equations I could possibly remove it.) Concerning the intercept: I base myself mainly on Box & Jenkins literature. Intercept as in $ y_t = \mu + \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $ crossed my mind, but I am unaware of any pro/contra arguments. You have any pointers? This author considers them the same: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352256/90490 which adds to the confusion.

Comment: It does not solve the problem entirely, but it helps. Normally in these models you’d use an informative prior and a restriction on the autoregressive parameter to be inside the stationary region. I can recommend the paper “steady-state priors for vector autoregressions” by Mattias Villani which deals with this issue but in a multivariate model.