# Interpret AR(3) output from `arima` function in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autoregressive

I have AR(3) like following. I'm not sure whether it is interpreted to
$$
Y_t = 5.6923 + 1.0519 Y_{t-1} -0.2292 Y_{t-2} -0.3931 Y_{t-3} + e
$$
or other? Thank you.

```r
Call:
arima(x = sqrt(hare), order = c(3, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3  intercept
      1.0519  -0.2292  -0.3931     5.6923
s.e.  0.1877   0.2942   0.1915     0.3371

sigma^2 estimated as 1.066:  log likelihood = -46.54,  aic = 101.08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Reproducing your problem

I could reproduce your model with the data from the TSA package (although I could not get the TSA package installed because it is not in support for my R version so I downloaded it)

```
> ### data from "https://github.com/cran/TSA/blob/master/data/hare.rda?raw=true"
>          
> mod <- arima(sqrt(hare), order = c(3, 0, 0))
> mod

Call:
arima(x = sqrt(hare), order = c(3, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3  intercept
      1.0519  -0.2292  -0.3931     5.6923
s.e.  0.1877   0.2942   0.1915     0.3371

sigma^2 estimated as 1.066:  log likelihood = -46.54,  aic = 103.08
```

#### Manually plotting the modelled values

Then I could plot the data along with two different ways of modeling the AR model.

```
# plot data
plot(sqrt(hare), type = "p", pch = 21 ,col = 1, bg = 1, xlim = c(1905,1940),
     xlab = "time (year)", ylab = expression(sqrt(hare)))

# manually modelling the data based on the coefficients
# using the linear model
y <- sqrt(hare) - mod$coef[4] # subtract intercept
x <- cbind(y[-c(1:2, 31)] , y[-c(1, 30:31)] , y[-c(29:31)])
prediction <- x %*% mod$coef[1:3]
lines(c(1908:1935),prediction+mod$coef[4])


# manually modelling the data based on an itterative scheme
series <- y[1:3]
for (i in 1:28) {
  last3values <- rev(series[c(0:2)+i])
  series <- c(series,  
              sum( c(mod$coef[1:3]) * last3values ) )
}
lines(1905:1935,series+mod$coef[4], lty = 2)

legend(1905,2.2,c("linear model", "recursion"), lty = c(1,2))

lines(c(0,3000),rep(mod$coef[4],2), col =8)
text(1938, rep(mod$coef[4],2),"intercept", col = 8, pos = 3)
```

[image: plot with two different ways to compute the model]

With the linear model I used *all* the data to predict the values. Each prediction is based on the previous three *observed* points.

With the recursion I used *only the first three data points* to predict all the other values. Each prediction is based on the previous three *predicted* points (and this makes that the error propagates and points further in time will be more wrong).

With the recursive formula the predictions get closer to the intercept. I guess that this is because the sum of your AR coefficients is below 1 (I am not sure that this is true, but intuitively I suspect that the value will go to zero when this is the case). I suspect that the coefficients of your fit are not very good to make predictions, because they do not represent the problem correctly. Probably you will need to investigate whether it is correct to use these three components (which is out of the scope of this question, which is a way for me to say 'I do not know how to do that').

#### The formula (answer to your question)

In both these cases, I have used the following formula:

$$(Y_t-5.69) =  1.05 (Y_{t-1}-5.69) - 0.23 (Y_{t-2}-5.69) - 0.39 (Y_{t-3}-5.69) $$

You can see the intercept as a term that is subtracted from the data to center it around zero. I have drawn the intercept with a gray line in the above plot. The intercept term will make the autocorrelation work with relation to a particular 'mean' value. Without that intercept the autocorrelation would be computed with respect to the 'zero' value.

#### Different expressions with the intercept term

In the code below I computed the ar model in 4 different ways and *each* of the methods represents the intercept term in a slightly different way.

```
> 
> ### manually fitting with linear model
> y <- sqrt(hare)
> ar1 = y[-c(1:2, 31)]
> ar2 = y[-c(1, 30:31)]
> ar3 = y[-c(29:31)]
> intercept = rep(1,28)
> modlm <- lm(y[-c(1:3)] ~ 0 + ar1 + ar2 + ar3 + intercept)
> modlm

Call:
lm(formula = y[-c(1:3)] ~ 0 + ar1 + ar2 + ar3 + intercept)

Coefficients:
      ar1        ar2        ar3  intercept  
   1.1528    -0.3294    -0.3880     3.1653  

> 
> ### three different functions to fit the ar model
> arima(y, order = c(3, 0, 0), method = "CSS")

Call:
arima(x = y, order = c(3, 0, 0), method = "CSS")

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ar3  intercept
      1.1528  -0.3294  -0.3880     5.6069
s.e.  0.1774   0.2682   0.1771     0.3239

sigma^2 estimated as 1.017:  part log likelihood = -44.25
> arima0(y, order = c(3, 0, 0), method = "CSS")$coef
       ar1        ar2        ar3  intercept 
 1.1599036 -0.3277354 -0.3880017  5.4146862 
> ar(y, method = "ols", order.max = 3)

Call:
ar(x = y, order.max = 3, method = "ols")

Coefficients:
      1        2        3  
 1.1528  -0.3294  -0.3880  

Intercept: -0.1197 (0.1917) 

Order selected 3  sigma^2 estimated as  1.017
>
```

I am not sure how all those intercept terms are represented. But anyway, the intercept term from the `arima` function can be related to the intercept of the simple `lm` function. This formula relates to [another answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352256/164061).

```
> modlm$coefficients[4]/(1-sum(modlm$coefficients[1:3]))
intercept 
  5.60692 
>
```

Which gives the same intercept term as the `arima` function when the method `CSS` is chosen. There will still be a slight difference with your outcome because the standard method is not `CSS` but some other function (which is an optimization of some likelihood function, but that is where my knowledge ends).